# Removing outer brackets from list of data

Tags: list-manipulation

I have a data list like below:

```
data = {{{-13.236, 25.903, 13.937}, {-22.42, -10.451, 24.981}, 
         {-2.877, -11.507, 33.117}, {6.905, -4.385, 39.751}, 
         {1.81, -22.179, 21.071}, {-16.151, -12.976, 25.321}}}
```

From here I want to make

```
data = {{-13.236, 25.903, 13.937}, {-22.42, -10.451, 24.981}, 
        {-2.877, -11.507, 33.117}, {6.905, -4.385, 39.751}, 
        {1.81, -22.179, 21.071}, {-16.151, -12.976, 25.321}}
```

How to do that?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use `First[data]` or `data[[1]]` or `Sequence @@ data`.

Update: Additional `Identity @@ data`

Comment: @Pavel..Thanks, First[data] or data[[1]] works fine but getting problem with Sequence @@ data...any comments?     Maybe Sequence @@@ data works.

Comment: Of course, `Sequence@@data` will be useful only in list context, i.e. `{a,Sequence@@data, b}` that replace `data` list by sequence of elements. Header `Sequence` remains on upper level (but `First@data == Sequence @@ data`). `Sequence@@@data` replace each inner List in outer List (remove `{}` of next level) that is not the same.

Answer (score 2):

Another option is Flatten, which is specifically designed for this problem.  Thus:

```
Flatten[data,1]
```

> {{-13.236, 25.903, 13.937}, {-22.42, -10.451, 24.981}, 
>           {-2.877, -11.507, 33.117}, {6.905, -4.385, 39.751}, 
>           {1.81, -22.179, 21.071}, {-16.151, -12.976, 25.321}}

and:

```
Flatten[data]
```

> {-13.236, 25.903, 13.937, -22.42, -10.451, 24.981, -2.877, -11.507,
>   33.117, 6.905, -4.385, 39.751, 1.81, -22.179, 21.071, -16.151,
>   -12.976, 25.321}